# React contolled component change value of select

Tags: reactjs

I have controlled component(I hope I understood the concept correctly).
Here is fragment of app.js (parent(main) component).

```
...

<Select options={this.state.patterns} 
default={this.state.activePattern} select={this.selectPattern}/>
```

Here is Select component. It is controlled - am I right?

```
    var Select = React.createClass({
        getInitialState(){
            return {
                value: this.props.default
            };
        },
        handleChange(e){
            var value = e.target.value;
            this.setState({value: value});
            this.props.select(value);
        },

        render(){
            return (
                <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                    {this.props.options.map(
                        (option, i)=>(
                            <option value={option} key={i}>
                                {option}
                            </option>
                        )
                    )}              
                </select> 
            );
        }   
    });
```

When user selects something - handleChange got called and we are happy.

---

But I also want to be able to change selected value from my app.js. 
How can I make that?

Comment: Your `Select` component must implement `componentWillReceieveProps`, so that you're able to update your local `state` when a new value is provided via incoming `props`

Comment: that solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three ways.

1) "Bad".

[Create the ref to the select](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute) at the upper level, and then call `setState` directly. `this.refs.mySelect.setState({ value : whaever });

2) "Better".

Manage the state at the upper level. Remove selection state (value) from the Select local state, and expose it through the props together with `select` callback. No additional lifecycle hooks (like `componentWillReceiveProps`) are actually required for that, you just need to remove something you don't need. Like this:

```
var Select = React.createClass({
    handleChange(e){
        var value = e.target.value;
        this.props.select(value);
    },

    render(){
        return (
            <select value={this.props.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                {this.props.options.map(
                    (option, i)=>(
                        <option value={option} key={i}>
                            {option}
                        </option>
                    )
                )}              
            </select> 
        );
    }   
});
```

3) "Best".

[Use value links pattern](https://medium.com/@gaperton/managing-state-and-forms-with-react-part-1-12eacb647112#.h45uuztor) to hide annoying callbacks. [Some good libraries](https://github.com/Volicon/NestedLink) may be helpful:

```
var Select = ({ options, valueLink }) => (
            <select value={ valueLink.value } onChange={ valueLink.action( ( x, e ) => e.target.value }>
                { options.map(
                    (option, i)=>(
                        <option value={option} key={i}>
                            {option}
                        </option>
                    )
                )}              
            </select> 
        );
```